# ¿Como editar un registro de una tabla en php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Muy buenas! Es primera vez que tengo este extraño error que aparece al tratar de editar un registro de la tabla llamada **estado** en formato php en conjunto con html en el base de datos aún utilizo PhpMyAdmin. He estado poniendome al dia con los inyecciones sql, para mantener la seguridad necesaria, aun sigo utilizando el Mysqli con estilo procedural.

**Tabla estado**

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.5.2
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 26-05-2017 a las 16:19:22
-- Versión del servidor: 10.1.21-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `webpractica`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `estado`
--

CREATE TABLE `estado` (
  `id_estado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Estado` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fecha_Creacion` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `estado`
--

INSERT INTO `estado` (`id_estado`, `Estado`, `Fecha_Creacion`) VALUES
(1, 'Completado', '2017-05-13'),
(2, 'Incompleto', '2017-05-13'),
(3, 'Analizado', '2017-05-13'),
(4, 'Bloqueado', '2017-05-13'),
(7, 'Inedit', '2017-05-26');

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `estado`
--
ALTER TABLE `estado`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_estado`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `estado`
--
ALTER TABLE `estado`
  MODIFY `id_estado` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**Editar.html**

```html
<form method="POST" action="editar.php">
id_estado: <input type= "text" name="id_estado"><br>
Estado: <input type="text" name= "estado"><br>
Fecha_Creacion: <input type="text" name="fecha" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid'); echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="editar" value="Editar informacion">
</form>
```

**editar.php**

```html
<?php
$msg = $id_estado = $estado = $fecha_actual = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['editar'])) {
 $id_estado = $_POST['id_estado'];
 $estado = $_POST['estado'];
 $fecha_actual = $_POST['fecha'];

 if ($id_estado && $estado && $fecha_actual) {
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "localhost", "webpractica");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
 }

 $query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE estado SET id_estado='$id_estado', Estado='$estado', Fecha_Creacion='$fecha_actual'");

 if(!$query) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
 } else {
  $msg = "Los datos se editaron correctamente";
    } 
 }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Al tratar de establecer editar el registro de una tabla, digamos el id 7 que se ve en el base de datos (la tabla estado), que sería 7, inedit, 2017-05-26 y luego de hacer submit, aparece este error:

[image: Error]

Lo que me hace preguntarme, no sé si hice bien por el query de mysqli de editar.php siguiendo el formato de mysqli estilo procedural, pienso que el error debe estar ahí o en la tabla estado? He investigado sobre ello y no hubo ninguna respuesta al respecto. Espero atento su respuesta!
Muchos saludos!

Comment: te faltael where en tu update

Comment: Creo que lo que esta mal es la sentencia SQL deberia de quedar de la siguiente manera: `UPDATE estado SET Estado='$estado', Fecha_Creacion='$fecha_actual' WHERE id_estado='$id_estado'`

Comment: Adema tus input type id_estado deberia estar como hidden y no deberia ser puesto por el usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que esta mal es que tienes mal tu sentencia `SQL` del `UPDATE`, la cual deberia de quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE estado SET Estado='$estado', Fecha_Creacion='$fecha_actual' WHERE id_estado='$id_estado'");
```

Te hace falta el `WHERE` para indicar a que registro en especifico quieres afectar. Para mas información puede checar la documentación de [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: Hice añadir lo del WHERE y funciona el editado, pero luego al actualizar la tabla, no está editada el valor del estado (Inedit a Edit), aún me parece extraño

Comment: La demas información si se actualiza? Solo fue esa el unico campo que no se actualizo?

Comment: Las demás informaciones no se actualiza, revisé la tabla y no esta totalmente editado. ese fue el unico campo que nunca actualizó, el Inedit

Comment: Cuales son los campos que si se editaron y cuales no?

Comment: Nunca fueron editadas, después de arreglar la sentencia sql del update luego de rellenar la información en editar.html, como cambiar el valor del id 7, que debería cambiarse Inedit a Edit y la fecha del mañana (27) y al aplicarle, apareció el echo del $msg y volviendo al phpmyadmin, el id 7 no está totalmente editada

Comment: Voy hacer la replica de lo que tratas de hacer en un momento encuentro el error

Comment: Realice las pruebas de manera local y si actualiza la información tal cual esta tu código con la modificación del SQL

Comment: del phpmyadmin? De ahi se debería ver el cambio?

Comment: Si en el phpmyadmin se ven reflejados los cambios!! Funciona perfectamente no se cual sea tu error

Comment: acabé de revisar el código del query del editar.php, estaba mal escrita, no me habia dado cuenta, si se pudo editar muchas gracias!

Comment: Para eso es el foro para ayudar, si te sirvio la respuesta favor de marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score -1):

No deverias actualizar la "id" si es calve primaria deverias utilizarla para diferenciar de los demas registros de la tabla luego del `WHERE`